# nested if statement C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, nested

I tried to write Nested if condition statement to calculate salary Raise in three condition, such as full-time, 2 part-time, or temporary. However, the result of salary Raise cannot be calculated. Are there any logic problems here. don't know where the mistakes are.  Please help. Thank you for your comment.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char employmentStatus;
    float performanceScore, salaryRaise = 0.0;
    double fullTimeSalary = 10000;
    double partTimeSalary = 8000;
    double tempSalary = 5000;

    double rate;
    double bonus =500;


    cout << "What is your employment status?" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 (full-time), 2 (part-time), or 3 (temporary)"<< endl;
    cin >> employmentStatus;

    cout << "Now enter your performance score" << endl;
    cin >> performanceScore;
    cout << endl;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);


    if (employmentStatus == 1)
    {
        if(performanceScore >= 8)
        {
            rate = 0.04;
            salaryRaise = fullTimeSalary * (1 + rate) + bonus;
        }
        else if (performanceScore < 8 && performanceScore >= 6)
        {
            rate = 0.025;
            salaryRaise = fullTimeSalary * (1 + rate) + bonus;
        }
        else
        {
            salaryRaise = fullTimeSalary; 
        }
        cout << "Your salary raise is: $" << salaryRaise << endl;
    }

    else if (employmentStatus == 2)
    {

        if (performanceScore >= 8)
        {
            rate = 0.03;
            salaryRaise = partTimeSalary + (salaryRaise*rate);

        }
        if (performanceScore < 8 && performanceScore >= 6)
        {
            rate = 0.015;
            salaryRaise = partTimeSalary + (salaryRaise*rate);
        }
        if (performanceScore < 6 )
        {
            salaryRaise = partTimeSalary 
        }
    }

    else if (employmentStatus == 3)
    {
        salaryRaise = tempSalary 
    }

    else 
    {
        cout << " No result" << endl; 
    }   

    cout << "Your salary raise is: $" << salaryRaise << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Couple missing semicolons in there. Compiler should be telling you where.

Comment: Hint: `char employmentStatus` is not the same as `int employmentStatus`.

Comment: What are your inputs? What are your expected outputs? What are your actual outputs? Leaving all that out means we only half the details to go on.

Comment: @Tom why not just  try using switch for clear code

Comment: Thanks, guys. I will try different ways to make it clear and more understandable since I already know the problems I have while using if statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems vary from logic to syntax.

Full code after my fix:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char employmentStatus;
    float performanceScore, salaryRaise = 0.0;
    double fullTimeSalary = 10000;
    double partTimeSalary = 8000;
    double tempSalary = 5000;

    double rate;
    double bonus =500;


    cout << "What is your employment status?" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 1 (full-time), 2 (part-time), or 3 (temporary)"<< endl;
    cin >> employmentStatus;

    cout << "Now enter your performance score" << endl;
    cin >> performanceScore;
    cout << endl;

    cout << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);


    if (employmentStatus == '1')
    {
        if(performanceScore >= 8)
        {
            rate = 0.04;
            salaryRaise = fullTimeSalary * (1 + rate) + bonus;
        }
        else if (performanceScore < 8 && performanceScore >= 6)
        {
            rate = 0.025;
            salaryRaise = fullTimeSalary * (1 + rate) + bonus;
        }
        else
        {
            salaryRaise = fullTimeSalary; 
        }
        cout << "Your salary raise is: $" << salaryRaise << endl;
    }

    else if (employmentStatus == '2')
    {

        if (performanceScore >= 8)
        {
            rate = 0.03;
            salaryRaise = partTimeSalary + (salaryRaise*rate);

        }
        if (performanceScore < 8 && performanceScore >= 6)
        {
            rate = 0.015;
            salaryRaise = partTimeSalary + (salaryRaise*rate);
        }
        if (performanceScore < 6 )
        {
            salaryRaise = partTimeSalary;
        }
    }

    else if (employmentStatus == '3')
    {
        salaryRaise = tempSalary;
    }

    else 
    {
        cout << " No result" << endl; 
        return 0;
    }   

    cout << "Your salary raise is: $" << salaryRaise << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

---

Problems detected and explained solutions:

1. Syntax: There are couple of semi colons missing, you should debug this yourself compiler tells you where exactly.
2. Logic: You were doing this  `if (employmentStatus == 1)` instead of `if (employmentStatus == '1')`, this not a problem on syntax level since C++ does implicit conversion of char to its ASCII code please see [my answer on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44551137/why-methods-dont-work/44551245#44551245) for better explanation.
3. Syntax: `system("pause")` look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong), [this](http://www.gidnetwork.com/b-61.html) and [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/36950/). Just drop it.
4. Logic: If there are no results you should quit don't go further and display the raise, hence you have to add  `return 0;` in the last condition.

Comment: Your comments are very helpful. Thank you so much. The second comment is the most important one that I don't know how to write.

Comment: Good luck Tom :)